# Regarding linux cp same directory Similar files to other directory and rename?

Tags: linux, copy, rename

I need copy some zip files(tea.zip, flower.zip, dog.zip) of "test" directory to "good" directory and rename them,I wish to use a command to complete the operation.

e.g.

source:  /home/**test**/,tea.zip, flower.zip, dog.zip

purpose: /home/**good**/,tea_ok.zip,flower_ok.zip, dog_ok.zip

1) How to write command at linux's ssh?

cp /home/**test**/[tea,flower,dog].zip /home/**good**/[tea,flower,dog]_ok.zip

Correct??

2) How to in bash?

**Supplement:I need copy files,not move,and copy to different directory ,rename them.**

Comment: Zsh has `zmv`, which can do this trivially, but it's more difficult within bash.  Also, you seem to think ssh is a different shell; it's not, it's just a connection that is probably (in your case) running bash on a different machine.

Answer (score 0):

It's intuitive to wirte this code.

```
mv /home/test/{tea,flower,dog}.zip  /home/{tea,flower,dog}_ok.zip
```

But it's wrong unluckily.

I think a consecutive command in shell can't fulfil your requirement.

You'd better write a simple shell script.

Answer (score 0):

This simple bash loop should work:

```
for i in /home/test/{tea,flower,dog}.zip; do
    echo mv "$i" "${i%.zip}_ok.zip"
done
```

Once you're happy with the script then remove `echo` before `mv` command.

Comment: Thank you,but I need:1) copy files,not move 2) from /home/test/ ,to /home/good/ ,can you help me again?